# htaccess - subfolder serve as root domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using 123-reg hosting and they have `main domain`features. Basically, it is putting your main domain (in 99% most valuable domain into root folder) with other less valuable domain in folders.

I'm looking for way to make subdomain work as root domain with .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?functionfactory.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/functionfactory.co.uk/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /functionfactory.co.uk/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?functionfactory.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ functionfactory.co.uk/ [L]
```

I'm nearly there, it is redirecting `www.functionfactory.co.uk` into  `functionfactory.co.uk folder, **but functionfactory.co.uk/index.html isn't redirected, why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 123-reg support we have a solution!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?functionfactory.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/functionfactory.co.uk/
RewriteRule ^(.*) functionfactory.co.uk/$1
```